# Understanding the output of a calculation

Tags: special-functions

I have a simple question about the output of a calculation. I have written a function which is a sum of 3j-symbols and Clebsch-Gordan coefficients in which I sum over various indices.

```
Jsymbol[l1_, l2_, S_, L1_, L2_, J1_, J2_] := 
 3*Sum[(-1)^(ml1 + b + mL)*(2 L + 1)*Sqrt[(2 l1 + 1)*(2 l2 + 1)]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0}, {l2, 0}, {L, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, ml1}, {l2, ml2}, {L, mL}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {L, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{1, b}, {1, c}, {L, mL}]*
    ClebschGordan[{1, mg1}, {1, i}, {1, b}]*
    ClebschGordan[{1, mg2}, {1, i}, {1, c}]*
    ClebschGordan[{l1, ml1}, {1, mg1}, {L1, ML1}]*
    ClebschGordan[{l2, ml2}, {1, mg2}, {L2, ML2}]*
    ClebschGordan[{S, MS}, {L1, ML1}, {J1, MJ1}]*
    ClebschGordan[{S, MS}, {L2, ML2}, {J2, MJ2}], {ml1, -l1, l1, 
    1}, {ml2, -l2, l2, 1}, {mg1, -1, 1, 1}, {mg2, -1, 1, 1}, {mL, -L, 
    L, 1}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -1, 1, 1}, {ML1, -L1, L1,
     1}, {ML2, -L2, L2, 1}, {MS, -S, S, 1}, {MJ1, -J1, J1, 
    1}, {MJ2, -J2, J2, 1}, {L, 0, 2, 1}]
```

When I plug in certain numbers for the indices I get

```
Jsymbol[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 (-(2/15) + 2[{-1/30, L>=1, 0 True}])
```

But how do I interpret this? I tried to perform the sums for the three values of L that I am interested in, $L=0,1,2$, separately, and I get $-1/3,0,-7/15$, respectively, which I can't make agree with the previous answer. What am I misunderstanding?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mathematica silently keeps a cache of all previous assignments to help speed things up, but this can sometimes surprise you if you do and then forget odd assignments. Because you have a `2[...]` in your output it is almost certain that you previously assigned `2` to some symbol which is later being used as a function name in your calculation. Do you get the same result if you restart Mathematica and don't do any other assignments before you do the single calculation you show above?

Comment: @Bill Interesting. Now that I restarted I get something slightly different, but still in the same form. $$3(1/5+2(-1/15, L>=2, 0~True)+2(-1/30, L>=1, 0~True))$$. I am just confused by the meaning of the True in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"] (* clear all prior definitions *)

Jsymbol[l1_, l2_, S_, L1_, L2_, J1_, J2_] := 
 3*Sum[(-1)^(ml1 + b + mL)*(2 L + 1)*Sqrt[(2 l1 + 1)*(2 l2 + 1)]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0}, {l2, 0}, {L, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, ml1}, {l2, ml2}, {L, mL}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {L, 0}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{1, b}, {1, c}, {L, mL}]*
    ClebschGordan[{1, mg1}, {1, i}, {1, b}]*
    ClebschGordan[{1, mg2}, {1, i}, {1, c}]*
    ClebschGordan[{l1, ml1}, {1, mg1}, {L1, ML1}]*
    ClebschGordan[{l2, ml2}, {1, mg2}, {L2, ML2}]*
    ClebschGordan[{S, MS}, {L1, ML1}, {J1, MJ1}]*
    ClebschGordan[{S, MS}, {L2, ML2}, {J2, MJ2}], {ml1, -l1, l1, 
    1}, {ml2, -l2, l2, 1}, {mg1, -1, 1, 1}, {mg2, -1, 1, 1}, {mL, -L, L, 
    1}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {b, -1, 1, 1}, {c, -1, 1, 1}, {ML1, -L1, L1, 
    1}, {ML2, -L2, L2, 1}, {MS, -S, S, 1}, {MJ1, -J1, J1, 1}, {MJ2, -J2, J2, 
    1}, {L, 0, 2, 1}]

result = Jsymbol[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

[image]

```
result // InputForm

(* 3*(-2/15 + 2*Piecewise[{{-1/30, L >= 1}}, 0]) *)
```

The last term is a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) function. The value of the Piecewise is `-1/30` if `L >= 1` or zero (default) otherwise. To simplify the expression use either

```
result // Simplify
```

[image]

or

```
result // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

The results for different values of `L` are

```
result /. {{L -> 0}, {L -> 1}, {L -> 2}}

(* {-(2/5), -(3/5), -(3/5)} *)
```

Assigning the values to `L` prior to calculating `Jsymbol` produces error messages and presumably erroneous results.

```
 Table[(L = val;
  Jsymbol[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), {val, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.